# Creating an entity with Breeze with a compound key that may already exist

Tags: breeze

I am creating a new entity with `manager.createEntity("Foo", { a: 1, b: 2});` 
The problem is `Foo` has a compound key. Both `a` and `b` are its PK values. So if I call `createEntity` this way, and the entity already exists, I get a MergeStrategy of Disallowed error.

What is the best practice here? Should I call `manager.fetchEntityByKey("Foo", [a,b], true)` to see if it exists first? Or should I wrap the `createEntity` call in a try/catch? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely call *fetchEntityByKey*.  The problem with just using *createEntity* with a try/catch is that this call MAY succeed because the 'new' entity is not yet in the cache because it has not yet been fetched but you will still get an error later when you try to save it because the server will detect that the entity cannot be added because it already exists. Better to always catch errors early ( failfast).

Comment: Thanks Jay. I realized later that this isn't really an issue 99% of the time when using createEntity, because you almost never set the PK value when creating the entity. That is almost always set on the server. But in this situation, and its probably just due to the legacy DB I'm dealing with, the entity has a compound PK, where 3 of its 5 properties compose the key. Thanks for the quick answer!